# Copy the data from a row to last row of another column

Tags: excel, vba

I get

> error 1004 VBA application defined

```vb
Sub Example()
Dim finalRowF As Integer

finalRowF = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
Range("A1").EntireRow.Copy Cells(finalRowF + 1, "H")

End Sub
```

Comment: You cannot copy a whole row into once cell...

Comment: Isnt it like coping a whole column and pasting on one cell? Like a copy paste?

Comment: Ou I see, the whole row is the whole worksheets row. ¿Is there a simple way of getting the whole row only with the data?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Sub Example()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim FinalRowF As Long

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change as necessary

FinalRowF = ws.Range("F" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                
Set CopyRange = ws.Range("A2:A" & FinalRowF)
CopyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
ws.Range("H2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```